# How to add cordova facebookconnect as dependency to a meteor package?

Tags: facebook, cordova, meteor

I would like to add com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect as a dependency to a meteor package.

Normally you add it with this code:

```
Cordova.depends({
  'com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect':'0.10.1'
});
```

but this gives me this error, since the app needs APP_ID and APP_NAME set on install.

```
Failed to install 'com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect':Error: Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME at...
```

(adding the plugin w meteor add cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@0.10.1 works w/o errors )

Answer (score 2):

Use `App.configurePlugin` inside the `mobile-config.js` file to set an `APP_ID` and `APP_NAME`: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/App-configurePlugin

```
App.configurePlugin('com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect', {
  APP_ID: "asdfasdgsdg",
  APP_NAME: "sadfasdfds"
});
```

Comment: Looks like the link has changed to this now: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs